# Defining an int Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, integer, int

Is there any difference between

```
int[] numbers = new int [] {1,2,3,4,5};
```

and

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

or do they express the same?

Which one shall be used?

Comment: use the second one - it's shorter ;)

Comment: They are exactly the same. Use whichever you find clearer.

Comment: @Logan Not exactly. The `new int[] {...}` must be used when the assignment is separated from the variable declaration (which is not the case in the OP's question). Doesn't matter if it is a field or a local variable.

Comment: First one is the proper allocation method in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the below method to understand the difference:

```
public int[] getFewInts() {
   // You can't directly return {1,2,3,4,5};
   return new int [] {1,2,3,4,5};
}
```

If you wanted to return an int[] array from a method in a single line, you can do that by simply `new int [] {1,2,3,4,5};` where as you can't do that with the other one i.e., `{1,2,3,4,5}`.

The same concept applies when you want to pass the `int[]` type as a parameter to a method.

Comment: Same when the declaration and the instantiation are on two statements. `int[] array; array = {1,2,3};` The notation can only be used during the declaration.